# Where can I download the latest SDK (4.9.2)

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfdcmobilesdk-android

In Github (salesforce-marketingcloud/JB4A-SDK-Android), I can only see etsdk-4.6.1.jar. 
In release history, the updated version is 4.9.2.

How can I download the latest SDK, 4.9.2?

Comment: Resolved. No question now.